# For Python 3.3, how can I make a list of functions using one lambda statement?

Tags: python, lambda, python-3.3

Here is what I tried:

```
quadrant = [lambda x, y: (sign[0] * x, sign[1] * y)
    for sign in ((1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1))]
```

What I expected to get from this line was a list of functions that each return the input values with some set of signs applied. For example, quadrant[1](x, y) -> (x, y), quadrant[2](x, y) -> (-x, y), and so on.

What I actually got is a list of four identical functions, all the last function that I put into the list. For example, quadrant[1](x, y) -> (-x, -y), quadrant[2](x, y) -> (-x, -y), and so on.

What am I misunderstanding here? Why does each new function added to the list replace all the previously added functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must break out of the closure:

```
quadrant = [ (lambda sign: lambda x, y: (sign[0] * x, sign[1] * y) ) (sign)
    for sign in ((1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1))]
```

Or with named functions as Blender pointed out:

```
def wrapper (sign):
    def makeQuadrant (x, y):
        return (sign [0] * x, sign [1] * y)
    return makeQuadrant

quadrant = [wrapper (sign) for sign in ((1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1))]
```

Or with a default named parameter as chepner pointed out:

```
quadrant = [lambda x, y, sign = sign: (sign[0] * x, sign[1] * y)
    for sign in ((1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1))]
```

---

And now to answer your question:

> Why does each new function added to the list replace all the
>   previously added functions?

No function is replaced, your list contains four distinct functions as you can see here:

```
quadrant = [lambda x, y: (sign[0] * x, sign[1] * y, id (sign) )
    for sign in ((1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1))]

for q in quadrant:
    print (id (q) )
```

What happens is that the value of `sign` is looked up when the function is called. The current value of `sign` is the last one assigned during the list comprehension, which is `(-1, -1)`. Which can be seen here:

```
quadrant = [lambda x, y: (sign[0] * x, sign[1] * y, id (sign) )
    for sign in ((1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1))]

for q in quadrant:
    print (q (2, 3) )
```

You might want to look a bit into "scoping" and "closures" for further reading.

Your example basically boils down to this:

```
fs = [lambda: x for x in range (10) ]
for f in fs: print (f () )
```

Comment: I think at this point a named helper function would make the code a little more readable.

Comment: Or simply make `sign` an unused parameter with a default value: `lambda x, y, sign=sign: ...`

Comment: @chepner Although without doubt your approach is the neatest, I fear that it is the most difficult to understand.

Comment: @Hyperboreus a name is useful in the stacktrace if it ever throws an exception.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, Thanks. I also appreciate chepner's fix, esp. with a small clarification: `...sign=dflt_sign: (sign[0]...for dflt_sign in ...`. The scope structure is clear in your explication of Blender's fix, but if straightforward readability is the goal, one may as well just write out `quadrant = [lambda x, y: (1, -1), lambda x, y: (1, 1), ...]`. I'm still curious how the list `[lambda: x for x in range(10)]` has 10 functions in it, which seems to mean that the for-loop was applied to each function, but only 1 value for x, which seems to mean that the for-loop also applied to x alone. No?

Comment: @Victor The last example is exactely the same scoping behaviour. Each function uses the name `x` which at runtime is loaded via `LOAD_DEREF`, hence it loads the current value of `x` which after the list comprehension is `9`.